# What is the ideal format/structure of urlconfs in django 2

Tags: django, urlconf

I creating an application and one of its urlconf is as follows

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', DashboardView.as_view(),name='dashboard:index'),
]
```

I am coming from PHP background (say Laravel) where we **name** our routes like below

- `dashboard:index` - for get
- `dashboard:store` - for post
- `dashboard:update` - for patch etc...

So I named my route as above, but while performing the system check, the following warning comes up.

> System check identified some issues:
>
> WARNINGS: ?: (urls.W003) Your URL pattern '' [name='dashboard:index']
>   has a name including a ':'. Remove the colon, to avoid ambiguous
>   namespace references.
>
> System check identified 1 issue (0 silenced).

So my question is what is the ideal naming format of URLs in Django in general.

- `dashboard_index` ?
- `dashboard.index` ?

Comment: The colon is typically not part of the name, this is for the namespace (you can write `namespace = 'dashboard'` before `urlpatterns = [...`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best place to find some kind of convention is in the [django admin app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/), where I found this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',
        views.BaseAdminDocsView.as_view(template_name='admin_doc/index.html'),
        name='django-admindocs-docroot'),
    url(r'^bookmarklets/$',
        views.BookmarkletsView.as_view(),
        name='django-admindocs-bookmarklets'),
    # and so on...
]
```

So, a string representing the url with dashes between words. I think is also important the name to be very explicit, not acronyms or shortened names.

**EDIT:**

Example of general url/path naming from the docs (2.1):

```
path('archive/', views.archive, name='news-archive')
```

Also it's a good idea to have in mind [python code style](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: well, your PEP link doesn't seem much of use here, because that's a general style guide, here I was asking about Django specifically, And, Django admin app is old, I think it was there since 2009, it's been ~10 years, and there is a chance that they haven't changed it so far, since the names are referenced in many places they didn't care to change it I think. Not sure about it though. thanks for the post BTW

Comment: @ShobiPP I referenced PEP because django uses python code style, docs: `Unless otherwise specified, follow PEP 8.`. If there is not a convention for naming urls (wich I guess you looked for but didn't find, as did I, and is very possible it doesn't exists), you can follow general ideas from it.

Comment: Also the fact that the admin is old doesn't invalidate it's coding style, that I doubt has changed much over the years. Look the year for PEP: 05-Jul-2001, 01-Aug-2013.